# Unable to get repr for <class xlwings.main.Sheet>

Tags: python, pycharm, xlwings

When examining a debug trace in PyCharm for the xlwings [Fibonacci](https://www.xlwings.org/examples) example, I get the following message against the following line of code:

`sht = xw.Book.caller().sheets[0]` *Unable to get repr for `<class xlwings.main.Sheet>`*

The code appears to run correctly, but can someone explain what the message means?

(python 3.6 and xlwings 0.11.4)

Answer (score 1):

`__repr__()` is a magic method which deals with the representation of the `xlwings.main.Sheet` object.

In this case, it is possible that the `xlwings.main.Sheet` class does not have a `__repr__()` method, which sets the representation of the class. If the code works fine without it, then it is nothing to worry about.